# Game of Life implementation is too slow

Tags: c++, game-of-life, opengl

I was tasked with implementing Conway's Game of Life. It seems to work fine but the implementation is lacking as I find that it takes a long time to generate the next generation of the grid. I'm looking for flaws and tips to speed up the process. Currently, I can only refresh the display twice a second.

The grid class and all its methods:
Grid.h

```
#pragma once
class Grid {
private:
    int species = 0;
    static int currentGrid[1024][768];
    static int nextGenGrid[1024][768];
    const int WIDTH = 1024;
    const int HEIGHT = 768;
public:
    Grid(int species);
    int getHeight();
    int getWidth();
    int checkCell(int x, int y);
    int checkNextGenCell(int x, int y);
    void changeCell(int x, int y, int species);
    void changeNextGenCell(int x, int y, int species);
    int numOfNeighbors(int x, int y);
    int Reproduce(int x, int y);
    void nextGen(int x, int y);
    void Update(int xStart, int xEnd);
    void Transition(int xStart, int xEnd);
};
    int Grid::currentGrid[1024][768];
    int Grid::nextGenGrid[1024][768];
```

Grid.cpp

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <algorithm> 
 #include <random>
 #include "Grid.h"
 #include <time.h> 

int Grid::currentGrid[1024][768];
int Grid::nextGenGrid[1024][768];
//populate the grid with different species of cells
Grid::Grid(int species) {
    this->species = species;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, species);
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
            //0 represents a dead cell
            currentGrid[i][j] = (int)dist(gen);
        }
    }
}
//return height of grid
int Grid::getHeight() {
    return HEIGHT;
}
//return width of grid
int Grid::getWidth() {
    return WIDTH;
}
//check species of a cell
int Grid::checkCell(int x, int y) {
    return currentGrid[x][y];
}

//change species of cell with int supplied
//shouldn't be called, only change next generation
void Grid::changeCell(int x, int y, int species) {
    currentGrid[x][y] = species;
}

//check species of a nextGen cell
int Grid::checkNextGenCell(int x, int y) {
    return nextGenGrid[x][y];
}

//change species of a nextGen cell with int supplied
void Grid::changeNextGenCell(int x, int y, int species) {
    nextGenGrid[x][y] = species;
}


//return the number of neighbors of the SAME species for a LIVING cell
int Grid::numOfNeighbors(int x, int y) {
    int numOfNeighbors = 0;
    //check conditions for specific species
    if (checkCell(x, y) != 0) {
        int xStart = std::max(x - 1, 0);
        int xFinish = std::min(x + 1, WIDTH - 1);
        int yStart = std::max(y - 1, 0);
        int yFinish = std::min(y + 1, HEIGHT - 1);
        for (int curY = xStart; curY <= xFinish; curY++) {
            for (int curX = yStart; curX <= yFinish; curX++) {
                //check if same species and ignore itself
                if (checkCell(x,y) == checkCell(curY, curX) && !(curY == x && curX == y)) {
                    numOfNeighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return numOfNeighbors;
}
//will look for 3 neighbors of the SAME species to ressurect a dead cell
//return the species that has 3 neighbors to this cell OR return 0 if condition not met
int Grid::Reproduce(int x, int y) {
    int xStart = std::max(x - 1, 0);
    int xFinish = std::min(x + 1, WIDTH - 1);
    int yStart = std::max(y - 1, 0);
    int yFinish = std::min(y + 1, HEIGHT - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= species; i++) {
        int numOfLivingNeighbors = 0;
        for (int curY = xStart; curY <= xFinish; curY++) {
            for (int curX = yStart; curX <= yFinish; curX++) {
                if (checkCell(curY, curX) != 0) {
                    //check if same species and ignore itself
                    if (checkCell(curY, curX) == i && !(curY == x && curX == y)) {
                        numOfLivingNeighbors++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (numOfLivingNeighbors == 3) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//call numOfNeighbors for living cell or Reproduce for dead cell, then update the corresponding nextGenGrid cell
void Grid::nextGen(int x, int y) {
    if (checkCell(x, y) != 0) {
        int neighbors = numOfNeighbors(x, y);
        if (neighbors < 2 || neighbors > 3) {
            changeNextGenCell(x, y, 0);
        }
        else {
            changeNextGenCell(x, y, checkCell(x, y));
        }
    }
    else {
        changeNextGenCell(x, y, Reproduce(x, y));
    }
}
//update the m x n cells of the grid to the next generation
void Grid::Update(int xStart, int xEnd) {
    //populate nextGenGrid with results
    for (int i = xStart; i <= xEnd; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
            nextGen(i, j);
        }
    }
}
//now transition currentGrid to nextGenGrid
void Grid ::Transition(int xStart, int xEnd) {
    for (int i = xStart; i <= xEnd; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
            changeCell(i, j, checkNextGenCell(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

and now for where the main gets executed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>
#include "Dependencies\glew\glew.h"
#include "Dependencies\freeglut\freeglut.h"
#include "Grid.h"
static const int numOfSpecies = 8;
static const int numOfThreads = 8;
Grid grid = Grid(numOfSpecies);
int threadWidth = grid.getWidth() / numOfThreads;

void nextGrid(int tid) {
    grid.Update(threadWidth * tid, threadWidth * (tid + 1) - 1);
}

void transitionGrid(int tid) {
    grid.Transition(threadWidth * tid, threadWidth * (tid + 1) - 1);
}

void refreshScreen(void) {
    std::thread t[numOfThreads];
    //populate nextgengrid with threads, split the task
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) {
        t[i] = std::thread(nextGrid, i);
    }
    //join all threads back
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
        if (i == numOfThreads - 1) {
        }
    }
    //transition the nextGenGrid to the currentGrid
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++) {
        t[i] = std::thread(transitionGrid, i);
    }
    //join all threads back
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.f, grid.getWidth(), grid.getHeight(), 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPointSize(1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.getWidth(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.getHeight(); ++j) {
            switch (grid.checkCell(i, j)) {
            case 0:
                //black
                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                break;
            case 1:
                //red
                glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                break;
            //...you get the idea
            case 10:
                //dark green
                glColor3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
                break;
            }
            glVertex2f(i, j);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //use factors of 1024 divide the grid evenly between threads
    //width of the screen 1 thread is responsible for
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(1072, 768);
    glutCreateWindow("The Game of Life");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(refreshScreen);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh copied accidentally, is present in .cpp

Comment: If you want it to run fast, you'll probably want (need) to write some code that runs on the GPU (e.g., implement it as a fragment shader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very straightforward and easy to understand, which is great! Keep that up!

## Profile

Whenever you're dealing with performance, the most important thing you can do is to profile your code to see where the slowdowns are. I can't tell just by looking at your code which part is slowing it down. I do see some things you could improve, though.

## Don't Send Individual Pixels to OpenGL

The biggest problem I see is that you're manually setting each pixel in the world on every loop. That's going to be time consuming. What you could do instead is upload the grid as a texture and blit it to the screen by drawing a screen-aligned textured quad with it. Rather than having a case statement that outputs a different color for each cell, simply call `glTexImage2D()` to upload the data as a 1-channel grayscale texture. You can then either use it directly to texture a quad (which would probably be too dark to show much, as you only have 10 values), or apply a fragment shader to sample it and do something with the result. For example, that case statement in `display()` could be moved into a shader, and possibly turned into a look-up table instead.

## Use Your Named Constants

You've gone to the trouble to use named constants for a number of values in your code, but you've neglected to use them everywhere. For example, in the definition of your `Grid` class, you have this:

```
static int currentGrid[1024][768];
static int nextGenGrid[1024][768];
const int WIDTH = 1024;
const int HEIGHT = 768;
```

Why wouldn't you define `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` before `currentGrid` and `nextGenGrid`, and then use them to define those 2 arrays? Like this:

```
const int WIDTH = 1024;
const int HEIGHT = 768;
static int currentGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
static int nextGenGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Also, you've multiply defined `currentGrid` and `nextGrid` both in the header (just after the class definition) and in the source file. I'm a little surprised your compiler doesn't warn you about that.

Also, why use constants and then have a `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` method that simply return the constants? If they can never change, and the constants are public, there's no need for those accessors.

## Other Optimizations

There are other types of optimizations you can make. One route to take is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). This is where you cache the results of a calculation and re-use it when your inputs are the same. You can get significant speed-ups by doing this with your grid. [See this article for more info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife).